# Monitor one host from two Nagios instances

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I have two Nagios (monitorA and monitorB) servers in different datacenters. On both I have configured same WWW host.
This works fine until there is a network problem between one Nagios host and WWW server.
When network problem occurs, I am flooded with false-positive notifications about unavailability of WWW host.
Question - is there a solution to some kind distributed monitoring? In example if there is network problem between monitorA and WWW server notification will not be send until there will be same problem on monitorB ?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

What Zoredache said;  I agree that it's not really a false positive.

Do you have parent hosts set up?  If so, Nagios can detect the difference between down and unreachable, and you can decide how to handle unreachable vs. down.  http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/networkreachability.html

Comment: Yes, I do. But in this case - who should be parent and who child ? monitorB to monitorA? What if network problem to WWW host occur on monitorB instead of monitorA ? Than there will be a problem in network (which I can not solve) but server WWW will still work...

Comment: Neither MonitorA nor MonitorB is the parent or the child.  The Child is WWW.  The parent is probably a router between MonitorA and WWW, or a router between MonitorB and WWW.  You don't need to get alerts for it, you just need enough to tell if it's the reason why your Monitoring can't talk to WWW.

Comment: This.  You need to monitor all the hosts between the nagios and the remote host that need to be up for the check to pass.  Alternatively, monitor google.com via check_http.  If that goes down, don't alert on anything.

Comment: Yes, it sounds simple for one host you monitor. How about infrastructure with many hosts to monitor (assume, that they are not in same DC) - will you monitor every network device between Nagios and monitored host? Amount of network devices will be much higher than monitored devices. Other thing is, that I can not be sure if network path change - this generates more problems with changing Nagios configuration.

Comment: `will you monitor every network device between Nagios and monitored host?` - No.  I would only monitor the hosts/networks that I have some ability to influence.  So I would monitor: my internal network,  the ISP providing network access to my internal network,  the network at my data center, and my host at the data center.  Everything between my local ISP, and the Data center network is outside my influence.  If there is fault between the two, I just have to identify on which end so I can call the DC, or ISP.

Comment: What Zoredache said.  If MonitorA, MonitorB, and WWW are all in separate datacenters that you control (or your company controls), I'd monitor the main router out of MonitorA, the main router out of MonitorB, and the main router into WWW.  Anything between them is not something I control.  I just want enough info to know whether the network or my host is the problem.

Comment: Well, this still means, that I need to monitor devices, over which I do not have control. What is more, I need to check periodically if network path didn't change.
What I was thinking about is rather some kind of monitoring from different places, like uptrends.com .

Comment: There's probably only one path out of MonitorA's datacenter, right?  Ditto for MonitorB.  That's two routers.  Don't get alerts for the routers, only get alerts for WWW.  The only reason you have the routers is solely for the difference between Down and Unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really sound like a false positive if your site cannot be reached from that network.  But you might be getting notices that are not useful if you don't have your dependencies/notifications setup in a way that is useful.

Can you setup a check to verify that the network link is good, between nagios instance and the network your web site is hosted on?  Then setup your dependencies and notifications so that you are notified that the link between the nagios system and the is the problem?

If you are monitoring the right things your nagios system should be telling you that the Internet link has failed at one of the datacenters rather then notifying you about all the services it can't reach because the network link is down.